# Check if file exists and move duplicates

Tags: powershell

I am trying to loop through a folder with several files to see if any of the files are duplicated in a shared network folder/folders. If so move them to a folder named ComparedDuplicates.

Problem 1:
Only `P:\clients\` is in common and very large.

The pattern is

```
P:\clients\"some-clientname"\EOB\"some-year"\"some-month"
```

I would like something closer to this:

```
P:\clients\*wildcard-or-list*\EOB\"search-the-rest-recursively"
```

Problem 2: Having the Get-ChildItem to work or do I use Test-Path?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#Common Paths
$PathFilesToCheck = "P:\GroupofFiles" #May have a folder in it - do not want to look for it in other folders
$PathFilesToCompareTo = "P:\clients\" #Needs to recusively look
$PathDupFolder = "$PathFilesToCheck\ComparedDuplicates" #Place holder for dulpicate files found.

#Variables
$FilesToCheck = Get-ChildItem "$PathFilesToCheck\*.*"

#Make a Duplicate folder (if folder does NOT exist) to hold duplicate files that were compared to the client folders.
If ( -Not (Test-Path -Path $PathDupFolder)) {
    New-Item "$PathDupFolder" -ItemType directory -Force |Out-Null #Out-Null makes powershell wait for the folder to be created before moving files.
}

#Loop through each file name and compare to client folders
ForEach ($File in $FilesToCheck) { #Loop
    $FileExists = Get-ChildItem -Path $PathFilesToCompareTo -Include $File -Recurse #Test if file name exist
    If ($FileExists -eq $True) { #File is a duplicate
        Move-Item -Path $PathFilesToCompare -Destination $PathDupFolder  #Move the file to the duplicate folder
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: ..And does what you have so far work at all? Any error messages? I don't really understand your problem #1, because i don't see any of that in the code you have shown. As for the final loop. Get-ChildItem returns a collection of `FileInfo` objects. To use this, instead of the $FileExists stuff, try `Get-ChildItem -Path $PathFilesToCompareTo -Include $File.Name -Recurse -File -Force | ForEach-Object { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $PathDupFolder }`

Comment: p.s. Comparing files only by name is not something i would do. What if the files with the same name have different content? (see `Get-FileHash`) or one file is more recent than the other?